# Realtime input change in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this script, all with javascript.

I only need set the value of the hidden input with `id="precio"` to the valor of the `.price` class, *(you can see total: xx € on top right)*

I need do this to pass the total price to the jcart shopping cart.

All done, I think correct, but isn't working.

```
$("#price").change(function() {
    var precio = $("#price").val();
    $("#cajaprecio").val(precio);
});
```

here is the full website for viewing to help me *(sorry for my english)* [link to the diseño web website](http://javiramos.com/pedidos/)

Comment: I don't see any error over you site. All changes are getting reflected perfectly. Can you explain some more ?

Comment: the cart doesn't update like it's supposed to.

Comment: @Deryck when i "configure" a product, you can see the "valor" of that product on top right, but when i click add, (it gets the price from #total-cost hidden input [updated, see the code plz :(]), it displays very extrange prices, not similar that setted.

Comment: Pienso que te ayudo pero yo necesito los buritos antes de morir.  How's that?  I'm a bit rusty lol

Answer (score 1):

OK got it.  You had the right idea with .change()

```
$("#price").change(function() {
    var precio = $(this).text();
    $("#precio").val(precio);
});
```

Also - This function pretty much removes the need for that blue "Order" button on the left since everything seems to be updated automatically anyway.

Of course, the values are incorrect but I'm still workin on that.

Comment: Without access to the site I can't do as much as I want but you'll need to make a PHP function to do a str_replace() on the #precio value because it's going to retain the Euro symbol and some spaces.  I'm guessing the checkout module needs this to just be a number.

Comment: Im triying to clean the number with javascript, but dont work:



`$("#price").change(function() {
    var precio = $(this).text();
    priceVal = parseFloat(precio.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, '')); // 12345.99
    $("#precio").val(priceVal);

});`

Comment: anyone can help me plz? im being crazy!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using keyup event to change the total price in real time.

```
$("#price").keyup(function() {
  var precio = $("#price").val();
  $("#cajaprecio").val(precio);
});
```

Comment: and, this contemplates when a user clicks a dropdown? or when a user click to add more units? (i don't know, but i imagine i cant do it whit this method.